# Получить имена доступных сетевых папок

Tags: c#, .net

Есть сервер с несколькими расшаренными папками, например

```
\\MyServer\Directory1
\\MyServer\Directory2
...
\\MyServer\DirectoryN
```

как можно получить список всех этих папок если

```
\\MyServer
```

не доступна?

Comment: Попробуйте через WMI: `GetObject("winmgmts:\\MyServer\root\CIMV2").ExecQuery("SELECT Path, Name, Caption FROM Win32_Share Where Type = 0")`

Comment: @Akina, да помогло. Оформите как ответ что бы я смог его принять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте через WMI:

```
GetObject("winmgmts:\\MyServer\root\CIMV2").ExecQuery("SELEC‌​T Path, Name, Caption FROM Win32_Share Where Type = 0")
```